# Not receiving events from Event flow in android

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-mvvm, android-event

I'm using MVVM architecture along with dagger hilt. I'm using event channel to send my events then retrieve them using event flow like shown below. I wanted to test everything by just ticking or unticking a checkbox which isn't working. From logcat I could see that my event was being triggered but some how is not sent or received.

State:

```
data class BottomNavigationSharedStates(

   val isPopupMenuShowing: Boolean = false,

   val showingVerseOfTheDay: Boolean = true,
   val showingDynamicWords: Boolean = true,
   val showingVerseGuesser: Boolean = true,

   val isCheckBoxTicked: Boolean = false,

   val isMenuSideBarShowing: Boolean = true,

   val isSearchBarExpanded: Boolean = true,

   val showingAddingVerseFloatingButton: Boolean = true,

   val lastOpenedTheme: String = "",
   val sortType: SortType = SortType.byDate,

   val selectedIndex: Byte = 0



)
```

Events:

```
 data class TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse(val isCheckBoxTicked: Boolean): BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents

    object HidePopUpMenu: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents

    object ShowMenuSideBar: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents
    object HideMenuSideBar: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents

    object ExpandSearchBar: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents
    object CollapseSearchBar: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents

    object ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents
    object HideAddingVerseFloatingButton: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents

    data class ChangeSortTypeTo(val sortType: SortType): BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents
```

In the View Model:

```
@HiltViewModel
class BottomNavigationSharedViewModel @Inject constructor(

    val daoFunctions: DataBaseRepositoryImpl

): ViewModel() {




  private val _state = MutableStateFlow(BottomNavigationSharedStates())


  val state = _state.stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), BottomNavigationSharedStates())


    val allVerses = Pager(

     config = PagingConfig(

         pageSize = 60,
         enablePlaceholders = true,
         maxSize = 200

     ) // PAGING CONFIG ENDS
 ) {


     daoFunctions.getVersesByDate()



 }// PAGER ENDS


    private val eventsChannel = Channel<BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents>()
    val eventFlow = eventsChannel.receiveAsFlow()



    fun onEvent(event: BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents){


        when(event){

            is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ChangeSortTypeTo -> triggerChangingSortTypeEvent(event.sortType)
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.CollapseSearchBar -> triggerCollapsingSearchBarEvent()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ExpandSearchBar -> triggerExpandingSearchBarEvent()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideAddingVerseFloatingButton -> triggerHidingAddVerseFloatingButton()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideMenuSideBar -> triggerHidingMenuSideBarEvent()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HidePopUpMenu -> triggerHidingPopUpMenuEvent()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton -> triggerShowingAddVerseFloatingButton()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowMenuSideBar -> triggerShowingMenuSideBarEvent()
            BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowPopUpMenu -> triggerShowingPopUpMenuEvent()
            is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.UpdateUiThemeTo -> TODO()
            is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse -> {
                Log.d("CheckBoxOnEvent", event.isCheckBoxTicked.toString()) // Testing to see whether event is triggered

                triggerTickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerseEvent(event.isCheckBoxTicked)
            }
        }


    }


    private fun triggerShowingPopUpMenuEvent(){

         viewModelScope.launch {

             eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowPopUpMenu)

         }

    }





    private fun triggerHidingPopUpMenuEvent(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HidePopUpMenu)

        }
    }






    private fun triggerShowingMenuSideBarEvent(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowMenuSideBar)

        }

    }





    private fun triggerHidingMenuSideBarEvent(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideMenuSideBar)

        }

    }






    private fun triggerExpandingSearchBarEvent(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ExpandSearchBar)

        }

    }





    private fun triggerCollapsingSearchBarEvent(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.CollapseSearchBar)

        }

    }







    private fun triggerShowingAddVerseFloatingButton(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton)

        }

    }





    private fun triggerHidingAddVerseFloatingButton(){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton)

        }

    }






    private fun triggerChangingSortTypeEvent(sortType: SortType){

        viewModelScope.launch {

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ChangeSortTypeTo(sortType))

        }


    }




    fun triggerTickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerseEvent(isCheckBoxTicked: Boolean)
    = viewModelScope.launch {

            Log.d("CheckBoxTrigger", isCheckBoxTicked.toString())

            eventsChannel.send(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse(isCheckBoxTicked))

        }































     fun showPopUpMenu(){


        _state.update { it.copy(isPopupMenuShowing = true) }


    }

    fun hidePopUpMenu(){


        _state.update {    it.copy(isPopupMenuShowing = false)    }


    }


    fun showMenuSideBar(){

        _state.update {     it.copy(isMenuSideBarShowing = false)    }

    }


    fun hideMenuSideBar(){

        _state.update {     it.copy(isMenuSideBarShowing = false)     }

    }


    fun expandSearchBar(){

        _state.update {      it.copy(isSearchBarExpanded = true)     }

    }


    fun collapseSearchBar(){

        _state.update {      it.copy(isSearchBarExpanded = false)     }

    }



    fun showAddingVerseFloatingButton(){

        _state.update {      it.copy(showingAddingVerseFloatingButton = true)     }

    }

    fun hideAddingVerseFloatingButton(){

        _state.update {      it.copy(showingAddingVerseFloatingButton = false)     }

    }



    fun changeSortTypeTo(sortType: SortType){


        _state.update {      it.copy(sortType =  sortType)     }

    }


    fun updateUiThemeTo(theme: String){


        _state.update {      it.copy(lastOpenedTheme = theme)     }

    }


    fun tickOrUntickMemoriseVerseCheckBox(isCheckBoxTicked: Boolean){


        Log.d("CheckBoxTrigger", isCheckBoxTicked.toString())


        _state.update {      it.copy(isCheckBoxTicked = isCheckBoxTicked)     }

    }





}
```

CheckBox:

```
  Checkbox(
                                        checked = state.isCheckBoxTicked,
                                        onCheckedChange = { isCheckBoxTicked ->

                                            Log.d("CheckBoxContent", isCheckBoxTicked.toString())


                                            onEvent(BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse(isCheckBoxTicked))
                                        }

                                    )
```

MainActivity:

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: BottomNavigationSharedViewModel by viewModels()



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)


        lifecycleScope.launch {

                viewModel.eventFlow.collect { event ->

                    Log.d("CheckBox","here")


                    when (event) {

                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowMenuSideBar -> viewModel.showMenuSideBar()
                        is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ChangeSortTypeTo -> viewModel.changeSortTypeTo(SortType.byDate)
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.CollapseSearchBar -> viewModel.collapseSearchBar()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ExpandSearchBar -> viewModel.expandSearchBar()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideAddingVerseFloatingButton -> viewModel.hideAddingVerseFloatingButton()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideMenuSideBar -> viewModel.hideMenuSideBar()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HidePopUpMenu -> viewModel.hidePopUpMenu()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton -> viewModel.showAddingVerseFloatingButton()
                        BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowPopUpMenu -> viewModel.showPopUpMenu()
                        is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.UpdateUiThemeTo -> viewModel.updateUiThemeTo(
                            ""
                        )

                        is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse -> {

                            Log.d("CheckBoxMain", event.isCheckBoxTicked.toString())
                            viewModel.tickOrUntickMemoriseVerseCheckBox(event.isCheckBoxTicked)
                        }


                    } // WHEN ENDS

                } // COLLECT ENDS







        }


        setContent {

            val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
//            val pagingItems = viewModel.allVerses.flow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
            val navController = rememberNavController()


          mainScreen(
              context = this,
              navController = navController,
              state.value,
              viewModel::onEvent)


        }
    }

}
```

I've tried to collect the events inside a composable using Launched effect + lifecycle but still got nothing, check box didn't tick at all

```
 setContent {

            val state = viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
//            val pagingItems = viewModel.allVerses.flow.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
            val navController = rememberNavController()



            val lifeCycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

            LaunchedEffect(viewModel.eventFlow,lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle){


                lifeCycleOwner.repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){


                    withContext(Dispatchers.Main.immediate){
                        viewModel.eventFlow.collect { event ->

                            Log.d("CheckBox","here")


                            when (event) {

                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowMenuSideBar -> viewModel.showMenuSideBar()
                                is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ChangeSortTypeTo -> viewModel.changeSortTypeTo(SortType.byDate)
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.CollapseSearchBar -> viewModel.collapseSearchBar()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ExpandSearchBar -> viewModel.expandSearchBar()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideAddingVerseFloatingButton -> viewModel.hideAddingVerseFloatingButton()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HideMenuSideBar -> viewModel.hideMenuSideBar()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.HidePopUpMenu -> viewModel.hidePopUpMenu()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowAddingVerseFloatingButton -> viewModel.showAddingVerseFloatingButton()
                                BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.ShowPopUpMenu -> viewModel.showPopUpMenu()
                                is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.UpdateUiThemeTo -> viewModel.updateUiThemeTo(
                                    ""
                                )

                                is BottomNavigationScreensSharedEvents.TickOrUntickCheckBoxToMemoriseVerse -> {

                                    Log.d("CheckBoxMain", event.isCheckBoxTicked.toString())
                                    viewModel.tickOrUntickMemoriseVerseCheckBox(event.isCheckBoxTicked)
                                }


                            } // WHEN ENDS

                        } // COLLECT ENDS




                    } // WITH CONTEXT ENDS




                } // OWNER ENDS









            }


          mainScreen(
              context = this,
              navController = navController,
              state.value,
              viewModel::onEvent)


        }
```

Everything seems fine but I don't know why I'm not receiving the event,Your help will be highly appreciated